# How to set home directory in Win10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I currently do not have a home directory on my laptop, and all users are under `C:\Users`. I want a folder, `C:\Users\username`, to become `C:\home\username`. On Linux I know this is mkhomedir_helper, but I am unfamiliar with how to implement this on Windows 10.

Answer (score 27):

### Find your [SID](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-an-sid-number-2626005)

Run the following command from the command prompt:

```
wmic useraccount where name="USER" get sid
```

Remember to replace `USER` with your username. Write this down as you will need it later.

(*[credit](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-find-a-users-security-identifier-sid-in-windows-2625149)*)

### Move your User Profile

Using an administrator account other than the one you want to move, copy the folder `C:\Users\Username` to `C:\home\username`.

Open Regedit to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

In the left pane under the `Profilelist` key, select the key that matches the SID your got before. In the right pane, right click on `ProfileImagePath`, and click on Modify. Enter the full path to where you copied your User Profile to (i.e. `C:\home\username`.

(*[credit](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/87555-user-profile-change-default-location.html)*)

Comment: Works fine, but may break some some applications. These can't find some of their old data anymore, due to hardcoded paths. E.g. MS Outlook 2016 and MiKTeX. I would recommand to avoid moving the user profile if the user already used the account.

Comment: also update your user variables in System properties.

Comment: `No Instance(s) Available.`

Comment: note that this wmic query no longer works in some cases (win10 pro) despite definitely plugging in a valid value for NAME

Answer (score 5):

(update: this might only work on Windows 10 Pro)

[Plonis answer](https://superuser.com/a/1190369/232770) is good but instead of going to the registry:

- start menu > type "users" > select "Edit local users or groups" (or lusrmgr.msc)
- double click Users
- double click the user you want to change
- Profile tab > Home folder > Local path > enter the new path

Comment: Um, no? https://imgur.com/uDRhfKi

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: And what is it supposed to work on?

Comment: When I posted this I was on Windows 10 Pro but today I'm afraid I can't test this anymore.

Comment: I just used this method. Worked fine. Thank you. (Windows 10 Pro)

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It leaves me with a "We can't sign you in into your account"

Answer (score 1):

In my case the $HOME environment variable didn't exist, so I created one.

1. From the Start menu, enter env to display the Environment Variables window.
2. Enter a new $HOME variable for my account:

Variable Name:
HOME

Value:
C:\Users\ThinkW541_User

Then when I call up PowerShell Administrator (not the Windows CMD window that this does not work in) I check it by entering:

$HOME

I get:
C:\Users\ThinkW541_User

From there I can use the $HOME variable in paths. For example:
wsl.exe --import Fedora-33 c:\distros\Fedora-33 $HOME\Downloads\fedora-33.tar

Answer (score 0):

The following steps work on Windows 10 Pro

1. Search for and open `lusrmgr.msc`
2. Open `Users` folder
3. Right click on the user you want to change
4. Select `Properties`
5. Select `Profile` tab
6. In the section titled `Home folder`, enter the new location of the home folder in `Local path`. Alternatively, you can map a drive letter to a network location.
7. Select `OK` to apply the changes
8. You will need to restart to see the changes take effect, shells will still consider the old location as `$HOME`

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It leaves me with a "We can't sign you in into your account"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this right because it sounds far too simple but I managed to change my home directory on Windows 11, as seen by gnu emacs and git bash, without using admin access:

- open a normal powershell window (not as admin)
- say e.g. `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HOME", "C:\home\YourName", "User")`, where `YourName` is your user name
- exit and reopen powershell (without that it didn't have an effect)
- say `Get-ChildItem Env:HOME` or `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")` to verify the effect.